# Argument of conditional MODE function

Tags: excel, if-statement, match, countif, mode

What is the purpose of adding {0,0} to the MATCH(...) function to be value_if_true part of a conditional MODE Excel function?

```
MODE(IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C1)=0,MATCH(A$1:A$43000,A$1:A$43000,0)+{0,0}))
```

This combination is now working well for my purpose, but I don't know what is the necessity of {0,0}

The difference is that with {0,0}, MODE will return all existent numbers firstly duplicated and then remnant in a range(here a column), but without it, MODE just returns duplicated(if any) or #N/A(if not).

Comment: `{0,0}` it creates an array of two values, which is added to the return value of `MATCH()` function to perform an array operation

Comment: I edited the main question.

Comment: Maybe it({0,0}) is created for being outputs writable in a range in a sheet!